# Verify "STOP! Look and Listen" audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2590304/1469208), which basically asks about unit of `duration` column in SQL Profiler. The [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2590345/1469208) to it (the only one) says:

> I found the answer here. It says: "In SQL Server 2005 and later, the SQL Server Profiler graphical user interface displays the Duration column in milliseconds by default, but when a trace is saved to either a file or a database table, the Duration column value is written in microseconds". I was watching them after saving the trace file in database.

My review queue come out with an answer:

> The server reports the duration of an event in microseconds (one millionth, or 10-6, of a second) and the amount of CPU time used by the event in milliseconds (one thousandth, or 10-3, of a second). The SQL Server Profiler graphical user interface displays the Duration column in milliseconds by default, but when a trace is saved to either a file or a database table, the Duration column value is written in microseconds.

I marked it as OK and got hit with "STOP! Look and Listen", because it is very low quality answer.

A screenshot of the error:

[image]

How, in the name of God, this can be a low-quality answer, if it is correctly formatted, it answers the question directly and it contains about 60% or more text from an answer that is valid, accepted and upvoted 24 times? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was added late (4 and a half years late) and did not add anything new to the accepted answer, and the poster was most likely hoping to farm some reputation by posting it. I suspect that it was caught in the Late Answer queue and the subsequent 2 downvotes and series of delete votes pushed it into 'Low Quality' territory.

Adding a late answer that echoes an already accepted answer doesn't add any value to a question, which is why it got the response it did.

However, that doesn't make for a great audit post for the LQ queue, agreed; it is not as if you can see enough context here. I'm not entirely sure how it could be removed from consideration however, since the post is actually deleted and we cannot add 'controversy' to it to remove it from consideration.

Comment: The problem is, that I don't see other answers, when doing review? I didn't know, that I have to review all other answers when doing review of particular one. And I don't know, if there are any proper flags to flag that answer is a duplicate of another.

Comment: @trejder: exactly, it is not a great review audit at all.